# Add ListBoxItem with Progressbar

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, progress-bar

Hey there i wondered how it is possible to add a ListBoxItem with a fully working Progressbar to a ListBox.

The Situation is:

I got a ListBox used as a Actionlog, i have a downloadfunction in the program and when i start downloading it appears in the log.

Now i wanted to Add a Progressbar to the Log which shows the downloadprogress.

I tried it by myself but not very successfully:

```
        ListBoxItem lbitem = new ListBoxItem();
        ProgressBar pb1 = new ProgressBar();
        pb1.Width = 100;
        pb1.Height = 20;

        lbitem.Content = "Downloading file - " + pb1;

        listbox1.Items.Add(lbitem);
```

But maybe this give you an idea what i'm actually trying to do.

I hope someone can help me out with this,

regards,

Jake

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly new to C# myself, so I may not have the full/right answer, but here is what I did in a similar situation.

Firstly, If you're using a progress bar, then you need to know the total number of items you're loading so you can tell the progress bar what the maximum value will be.
Then you set up a loop to load the listbox with data and incrementing the count of the progress bar.

A few words about the loop:
If the progress bar count exceeds the maximum value you have set, you will get a run time error.
If you are loading a LOT of items into the listbox, then don't update the progress bar every single time, rather do it every 10, 20, 50, 100 items (you shouldn't really have a listbox with thousands of items anyway, it's pretty inefficient).
You may need to refresh the screen display so the user can see the progress bar in action if you're in a tight loop.

Here's a little sample "air code":

```
pb1.Maximum = maxNumberItemsToLoad;
for (int i==0; i<maxNumberItemsToLoad; i++)
{
   lbItem = "String to add to Listbox"; //Read/Get your data to put into listbox here
   listbox1.Items.Add(lbItem);
   pb1.Increment(1);
   //May need to do a this.Refresh(); here if pb1 does not update
}
```

Comment: Guess you misunderstood something. I don't want to fill the progressbar with every added item. It is a log which should look like this: http://s7.directupload.net/images/120503/9vx8zjc4.png

I did this only with xaml which is easy, but i need to know how i can add a listboxitem like this in my codebehind.

Comment: I found the solution by myself now, i just needed to use a container, in my case a StackPanel and add the progressbar to it. Then i can add the StackPanel to my item and add it to the listbox. Works perfect

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
...
lbitem.Content = pb1;
...
```

In the XAML, on the instance of the ListBox:

```
<ListBox ...>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
             <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                 <TextBlock Text="Downloading file - " VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                 <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding }"/>
             </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
....
</ListBox>
```

A better way would be to have a list that holds the progress for each item (i.e. the value of the progress bar) and the `ProgressBar` is part of the `DataTemplate`.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use `ListView` to add `ProgressBar`.

Look at this : [A much easier to use ListView](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16009/A-Much-Easier-to-Use-ListView)